# On a 50 question multiple choice exam with 5 choices per questions, What are the odds that I get 100% if I were to Guess every answer?

Tags: probability, statistics, experimental-mathematics

What would the odds be to get 100% on a multiple choice exam where I guessed the answer to all 50 of the multiple choice questions (5 choices per questions)?

A 1 in how many chance?

Comment: "experimental mathematics" lol

Answer (score 3):

In every answer, you have $\frac15$ chance to guess the correct answer. You need that chance to occur all the $50$ time, and since all of your answers are independent events, you need to multiply these probabilties, therefore your chance: $(\frac{1}{5})^{50}=\frac{1}{5^{50}}$, which is not too big, you should learn for your exams. :)

Comment: I believe that you meant $(1/5)^{50}$, not $(1/50)^{50}$.

Comment: Yes, thanks for correcting.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure!   And +1 for the answer